# Don't handle the concurrent sometimes?

Tags: php, linux

my codes is:

```
$b_data_proxy = $dn." ".$cv." ".$dom_name." ".$record_ttl." ".substr($now,0,strlen($now)-1).$more_ip_address;<br>
                        $b_ftemp = fopen("$fdoc_spool/temp_b", 'a+');<br>
                        fwrite($b_ftemp, $b_data_proxy."\n");<br>
                        fclose($b_ftemp);
```

As you see, when one user access the page, this is right. 
but two users access the page at the same time. they will write the 
same file of temp_b. I don't want to use different name of temp_b.

This maybe a problem, they will write the same file in the same time.
But the size of  $b_data_proxy is less than 4kB.
So I want to know whether I should handle the concurrent?
Because the size is less than 4KB.

My system information:
Linux YF-2321 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 14:58:14 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thank you.

Comment: It might make most sense to use different access files: $fdoc_spool."/temp_b_".uniqid()

Comment: Thank you, actually I store the infromation in the same file.so the file name can't be differrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about them writing to the same file at the same time, then just use a temporary file unique to each user for the writing. Then remove the primary file and rename the temporary file to the name of the primary file. The last one to move the file will always win. Using this method, your file will not ever be in a corrupted state and you don't have to get into file locking / concurrency techniques.

Comment: Thank you. The differrent names is a good way. And I want to know 4kB is a safe size ,the linux kernel can protect this operation of write form other processes.

Comment: It will not matter how much data you are writing. The move operation will always result in one complete file by that name since you are writing to a temp file with a unique name first.

Answer (score 0):

Put a lock around the file with something like memcache or use a database.

```
if( file_not_locked )


    //create lock
    //open file 
    //do stuff
    //close file
    //free lock
```

Comment: Thank you. If I lock file, there are a race condition.so how to handle it ? an ex Lock maybe make some users wait a long time.